# Workaround to use css page-break properties in chrome for printing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

My task : to print the part of webpage with custom css and break the page from particular div and avoid page break from specific div.

My approach : 
-> i am getting values from the web page using javascript and creating my own divs with desired values dynamically and attaching them to a hidden div already exists on the page which has id for css to know its print part.
-> everything is good till this point that i am getting what i wanted for print but ***one requirement is that it should not break the page within specific divs ( This is main problem )*** and from particular div it must be separated ( this is done).

-> Properties i am using in my css are

```
/* Page break properties */
/* breaks page after first workout  */
#WorkoutAfterOne{
    display : block;
    page-break-before: always !important;
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}
/* Do not break page in this div */
#noPageBreak{
    display : block;
    page-break-before: avoid !important;
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    page-break-after: avoid !important;

}
```

I have searched for the solution but i am unable to get it. First what i have found is not to use properties like float or display block etc.. but for my task its required or i can say very hard to avoid. so i am looking for a workaround.

Comment: As a note ... These two items ... page-break-before: avoid !important; and page-break-after: avoid !important; have absolutely nothing to do with not allowing a break inside. They mean don;t do a break right before or after it, in essence keep this glued to what was before it and after it. If those things are also large, what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my solution by using this css property..

```
-webkit-region-break-inside: avoid;
```

Hope it will help if not try to add

```
display : block;
page-break-inside: avoid !important;
```

Thanks..!